# iOS Core Animation Police Light Flashing Light Effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation, quartz-graphics

**EDIT:**  *Per the provided comments, I have specified my question to a more direct implementation and desired solution.*

Hello there,

I want a **blue light**, a **red light**, and **potentially a neutral colored light**, all appearing to be spinning in circles (similar to if a police car was nearby, you would see the lights flashing/rotating colors).

Here's a screenshot of the red and blue image views that I'm currently using to try to make the effect.

[image: example screenshot of red and blue images]
The following code currently varies each view layer's opacity:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.5
                      delay: 1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     [self startRedAnimation];
                     [self startBlueAnimation];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```

My animation method looks like the following:

```
- (void)startRedAnimation
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    [animation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.75]];
    [animation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.1]];
    [animation setDuration:0.5f];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction
                                  functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];
    [animation setAutoreverses:YES];
    [animation setRepeatCount:16];

    [[_redLightView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"opacity"];
}
```

You can imagine that the blueLightView animation method looks similar.

What I'm looking for is to have the views appear to rotate, IE they are not just flashing their opacity from 0 to 1, but rather altering color and/or rotating around in a circle on the view.

I'd like to use `QuartzCore` and `CoreAnimation` frameworks to make this happen, instead of just `UIView` animations over an array of images.

I'm relatively new to CoreAnimation and have performed similar effects like rotating/pulsing view layers, but I'm just not certain what I could use from the framework that would give me the effect I'm looking for.

**Any insight would be greatly appreciated**! Thanks Stack Overflow peers!

Comment: The question is overly vague/ambiguous. There are infinitely many graphical styles (think; "comic book style", "realistic", "etc) and methods for drawing each of these things would vary. The question isn't asking a specific technical question - it's a general question for which I couldn't even provide an outline of what an "acceptable answer" would contain.

Comment: If you can show a video or sketch of what you'd like it to look like, that will narrow the question down a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, guys.  I have attached a screenshot of what I'm working with, as well as some sample code with my existing functionality.  Hope this has helped make my direction seem more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the images instead of changing the colors. I could imagine that you could achieve the desired effect by rotating the images around the bottom of the screen back and forth.[image: Illustration of the rotating light]